# AWS Lambda & Node: Send data from S3 to client with stream

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, stream

How i can send file from S3 to client in AWS lambda node js using stream?
I find in internet no advice.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details. For example, what do you mean by "using stream", and "from S3 to client"? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have client (React JS), backend (AWS serverless nodejs) and s3 bucket. I need have feature that download files in client side from S3. But S3 save sensitive data, so client should be able to request this data in backend. Client and backend use REST API. Since the files can be large, then I need the streaming. So, question is: 'How i can response file to client using streaming?'

Answer (score 0):

I find the decision of my task. It use the pre-signed URLs. For example: https://sanderknape.com/2017/08/using-pre-signed-urls-upload-file-private-s3-bucket/